# Data Initialization in certain table at the time of publish

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I develop my database in Visual Studio by selecting the SQL Server Database template. I may create the database and publish it from time to time since I may require to make changes and edit things at the time of development. The thing is that there are tables such the `Roles` table that may require some default data which now I may add manually by writing and saving a query file or using SQL Management Studio for that. But the problem arises when I have to hand out this DB to the customer, and the customer may not have any knowledge SQL things. I've been thinking if there is a way to write something at the time of table definition to automatically add and initialize some default value (if not already available in the table) by the time of publishing the DB, it would be very helpful.

For instance, given the below script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)
```

is there any way to add something to the above code to initialize the below automatically by the time of publishing the db if such records are not already available in there :

```
Id        Title
1         Admin
2         Management
3         Staff
4         Customer
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand you well, but `if you want to create table if not exists and insert data if the data not exists`, you can try this:

```
if not exists (select * from DatabaseName.sys.tables where name = 'Roles')
begin
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)
end
go
if not exists(select * from Roles where id='1')
Begin
insert into Roles (id,title) values (1,'Admin')
end
go
if not exists(select * from Roles where id='2')
Begin
insert into Roles (id,title) values (2,'Management')
end
go
.
.
.
```